# Sending variable to a function through javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to send a variable through to a function when clicking an image, but can't get any of it to work. not sure where I am going wrong.?

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cibravo/rNGMR/

HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="send" onclick="alert('works')" />
<br/><br/>

<img onclick="alert('works')" src="http://firmakurser.studieskolen.dk/images/web/Facebook-logo-small.png" />

<br/><br/>
<!-- this doesn't work -->
<input type="button" value="send" onclick="myFunction()" />
<br/><br/>
<!-- this doesn't work -->
<img onclick="showhide('works')" src="http://firmakurser.studieskolen.dk/images/web/Facebook-logo-small.png" />

JS

function myFunction(){
    alert("works");
}

function showhide(field){
    alert(field);
}
```

Comment: Please read jsFiddle's documentation: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar and learn [how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript on jsfiddle.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456361/javascript-on-jsfiddle-net)

Answer (score 1):

Both of your examples that you say don't work will work **provided** the functions they call are globals, not contained within any scoping function.

The reason it's not working in your fiddle is that jsFiddle's (surprising) default is to wrap your JavaScript code in a `window` `load` event handler, like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // your code here
};
```

...so your functions aren't globals. (I say it's surprising because waiting until the `window` `load` event runs, which is very late in the page load process, is not best practice.)

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rNGMR/4/ As Juhana points out, you change tehs second drop-down box on the upper left to one of the "no wrap" options (I went with "no wrap - body").

For clarity, here's a complete all-in-one example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/udafaj/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/udafaj/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Global Functions</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" value="send" onclick="alert('works')" />
<br/><br/>

<img onclick="alert('works')" src="http://firmakurser.studieskolen.dk/images/web/Facebook-logo-small.png" />

<br/><br/>
<!-- this doesn't work -->
<input type="button" value="send" onclick="myFunction()" />
<br/><br/>
<!-- this doesn't work -->
<img onclick="showhide('works')" src="http://firmakurser.studieskolen.dk/images/web/Facebook-logo-small.png" />
<script>
// Note that these are globals
function myFunction(){
    alert("works");
}

function showhide(field){
    alert(field);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In other words, pick either of the "no wrap" options from the second dropdown menu on the top left. http://jsfiddle.net/rNGMR/1/

Answer (score 1):

**More or less an alternity to your current approach**
(which was solved while I wrote this.)

Please try avoid using the 'onclick' event when you work on bigger projects. It's usually better to keep HTML, CSS und JavaScript modularly separated.

---

When I encounter problems like this I usually use anonymous functions, who then call the
function with the right parameters.

This technique also solves the problem that everything needs to be global -- which is discouraged too.

It suited me well trough the last 3 years and around 15k lines of JavaScript code.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8jSaT/1/

```
<!-- HTML -->
<img id="btnSomething" src="http://firmakurser.studieskolen.dk/...">

// (plain) Javascript 
var btn = document.getElementById('btnSomething');

// this is where the anonymous function comes in:
// Its only purpose is to redirect the onClick-Event
// and serve proper parameters
var btn.onclick = function() { showhide('works'); };

// Your code
////////////////
function myFunction(){
  alert("works");
}

function showhide(field){
  alert(field);
}
```